# How do I extract a copy of every historical version of a file from git?

Tags: git

Since it's a binary file, it's not much use for me to look at diffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to write a little script around `git log` and `git show` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DONE=false
FILE="$1"
EXPORTFILE=/tmp/exportfile
git log --pretty=format:"%h" "${FILE}" |until $DONE
do read || DONE=true
  echo "Exporting $FILE as of commit $REPLY to $EXPORTFILE-$REPLY"
  git show $REPLY:"$FILE" > $EXPORTFILE-$REPLY
done
```

This will export every known committed version of the first argument in the current branch to `/tmp/exportfile-12345678`.

<sup>Why the `until`, `$REPLY` and not just `while read $commit`? You'll miss out on the last line/commit. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165135/how-to-use-while-read-bash-to-read-the-last-line-in-a-file-if-theres-no-new) on more about that.</sup>